# Changes made to the ini file are not reflected in phpinfo()

Tags: apache-http-server, fedora, php, php.ini

According to `phpinfo()`, the following INI files are loaded:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php.d 

Additional ... /etc/php.d/40-memcache.ini
```

I edit the latter and change the following values:

```
memcache.prefix_host_key    Off Off
memcache.prefix_host_key_remove_subdomain   Off Off
memcache.prefix_host_key_remove_www On  On
```

to

```
memcache.prefix_host_key    On  
memcache.prefix_host_key_remove_subdomain   Off
memcache.prefix_host_key_remove_www Off
```

Also, I uncomment `session.save_handler` and `session.save_path`. Save, `systemctl restart httpd`, it is successfully restarts Apache. The values in `phpinfo()` do not change. Since the file `/etc/php.d/40-memcache.ini` is the only one that loads `memcache` extension it should also affect its settings. Why does it not?

I continue editing the INI files and discover that `10-opcache.ini` has the same problem: it does not affect the values reported by `phpinfo()`.

By the way, Fedora and PHP versioned tags on this resource are outdated by at least one decade. Someone should add fedora-36 and php8.

Comment: You restarted *httpd*, but are you using *mod_php*? Modern setups often do not.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that it is necessary to restart `php-fpm` service as well.

Now, the changes above are applied but the change to `session.save_handler` and `session.save_path` are still not applied, even after I commented out `session.save_handler=files` in `php.ini` and uncommented it in `40-memcache.ini`.

Comment: It is in fact the only service you need to restart if using _php-fpm_.